# Typedef for 2 dimensional array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, typedef

Is there a way to typedef a 2 dimensional array in C? Something like:

```
typedef char[10][10] board;
```

This example doesn't compile. Is there any way to do it? Or any other solution?

Comment: did you try: typedef char board[][10]; ?

Comment: How would you define a variable called `board` as a 2D array?  Answer: `char board[10][10];`.  To create a typedef `board` instead of a variable, use the 'storage class' `typedef`:  `typedef char board[10][10];`.  You can then create 3 boards using: `board b1, b2, b3;`.  You could also create an array of boards: `board ab[10];`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
typedef char board[10][10];
```

Then you can define new array as this:

```
board double_array = {"hello", "world"};
```

It's the same with:

```
char double_array[10][10] = {"hello", "world"};
```

Comment: what will be the new definition for the 2  dimensions array?

Comment: @user2216190: do you mean 'given a valid `typedef` of `board`, how will you create variables of that type?'  If so, the answer is `board b;` creates a variable `b` of type `board`, which is fully equivalent to `char b[10][10];` (because a `typedef` introduces an alternative name for a type, not a new type).

Comment: When declared with board double_array = {"hello", "world"};
How do I access the array elements?

Comment: board a[25]; //is it similar to char a[25][10][10];

Answer (score 5):

**Type Definition Statement**

> The type definition statement is used to allow user defined data types
>   to be defined  using other already available data types.

**Basic Format:**

> ```
> typedef existing_data_type new_user_defined_data_type;
> ```

So , yours should be :

```
typedef char board[10][10];
```

You can use it as Yu Hao has said OR you can also use it with char pointers to define a 2D array like this :

```
typedef char *board[10];
```

And then you can do as described by YU Hao.
In such a way you need not hard code the number of characters you want to use for the strings.

Comment: With the name `board`, it is likely that the type will be used to represent a game board, and will not be used to hold strings per se.  That's a minor detail though.  Also, strictly `typedef` gives a name (alias) to an existing type, rather than creating a new type.  That is a subtle detail and doesn't materially detract from your answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well, yeah !! point taken  sir, that seems more probable with that thanks !!